# How to put active bootstrap class on li element depending on the page

Tags: css, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

The title may seems weird but I'll try to explain it briefly... So In my admin section I extend a layout with a Sidebar displayed as a bootstrap list on every page.

Depending on the page I'm at, I want to put an active class on a specific li but I'm not sure what's the usual method to do this in a Laravel project..

I thought about putting a js script in every page, but that's not smart at all...

So i would like your advices guys, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong in this post, dudes ?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have much experience with PHP/Laravel but I think the best way would be to get your route and check against that

```
<li{{ $pageRoute == 'yourPage' ? ' class="active"' : '' }}>
```

Comment: That's what I needed :  <li class="list-group-item {{ Request::url() == route('recommandations.confirmed') ? 'active' : '' }}" id="list-confirmed">

Comment: How can you do that when you have a wildcard in route? like `user/edit/{id}`.

Comment: Perhaps you could use preg_match which can use to check that the expression "/yourId" is there on the link

Answer (score 1):

Add a helpers file inside `App` folder, create a function to add class in your desire element.

You can follow these steps below:

1. Create a new file inside `App` folder. Example: `helpers.php`
2. Inside `helpers.php` add this block of code:

   ```
   function isActive($path, $active = 'active'){
       return call_user_func_array('Request::is', (array)$path) ? $active : '';
   }
   ```
3. Add the file in `composer.json`. It will autoload the `helpers.php` whenever the project run. Inside `composer.json` add those lines

   ```
   "autoload": {
       ...
       "files": [
           "app/helpers.php" //warning: sometimes filename may case sensitive depending on your server
       ]
   },
   ```
4. Then, go to console and run `composer dump-autoload`
5. Now, you are ready to use `isActive()` function. Exaple:

   ```
   <li class="nav-parent {{ isActive('products') }}">
   ```

**More Tips:**

You can use wildcard inside `isActive()` function like `isActive('product*')`. `*` is indicating the wildcard.

You can even a pass an array of routes in `isActive()` function. Example:

```
<li class="nav-parent {{ isActive(['*product*','brand*','color*','size*','*categor*']) }}">
```

Comment: Nice idea, thanks man.